# How to assert type in a Rust macro?

Tags: rust

I created a macro function `my_macro`:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($param1:expr, $param2:expr) => {
        // ...
    };
}
```

How is it possible to assert that `$param1` is the type `MyType`? Is it possible to check for something more complex like `Box<T>`? Or even the return type?

I've found [assert_type_eq](https://docs.rs/assert-type-eq/latest/assert_type_eq/macro.assert_type_eq.html), but the documentation about it is confusing, and I don't see how to use it. Or if it is the best approach for the task.

I would like to add these type assertions to my macro, to make it easier to find out if it is used incorrectly.

Comment: If `$param1` is supposed to be `MyType`, why make it into a parameter in the first place? Simply use `MyType` directly in the macro.

Comment: Macro expansion happens before there are any types, so the best you can hope for is for your macro to generate some code that will check the types later. Something like `let p1: MyType = $param1;` will work, `assert_type_eq` will also work.

Comment: I believe what @kaya3 is pointing out with `let` is idiomatic, from what I've seen in the wild.

Answer (score 6):

Assign it to an explicitly typed variable:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($param1:expr, $param2:expr) => {
        {
            let param1: u64 = $param1; // compiling will throw an error
                                       // if the result isn't a u64
            let param2: u64 = $param2;
            
            param1 + param2
        }
    };
}
```

This also has the benefit of ensuring that the `$param1` expression is only evaluated once.